# jQuery .each method returning last value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel like the .each() method isn't really working. Here is my code:

```
function makeHTML(data) {
console.info(data.categories);

$(data).each(function () {
    let createButton = `
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                        <a href="${data.categories.category.id}" 
                        target="_blank">${data.categories.category.title}</a>
                    </button>
                </div>
                `;
    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = createButton;
});
}

$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "json/data.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: makeHTML,
    error: function (result) {
        console.error(result);
    }
});
});
```

It's only returning the last set in the json which looks like this:

```
{
  "categories": {
    "category": {
      "title": "Something",
      "id": 1
    },
    "category": {
      "title": "Something Else",
      "id": 2
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding debugger; immediately after the innerHTML = createButton; to watch the loop, but it goes into jQuery just once. It's weird. I don't know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the purpose of the each? I don't see you use any parameters inside the callback... Wouldn't `data.categories` always be the same thing?

Comment: `categories` is an object that has the property `category` _twice_.

Comment: As suggested, you probably want `categories` to be an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change it to :

```
{
  "categories": {
    "category1": {
      "title": "Something",
      "id": 1
    },
    "category2": {
      "title": "Something Else",
      "id": 2
    }
  }
}
```

Your code will recognize both objects, so you cannot stack them like that. JSON overwrites its attributes and sees only one version. You need to change it to an *array*.

Log from firebug :

> Object { category1={...},  category2={...}}

You should change function to :

```
function makeHTML(data) {
console.info(data.categories);

$(data.categories).each(function (index, data2) {
    var createButton = `
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                        <a href="${data2.id}" 
                        target="_blank">${data2.title}</a>
                    </button>
                </div>
                `;
    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += createButton;//add not set
});
}

$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "json/data.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: makeHTML,
    error: function (result) {
        console.error(result);
    }
});
});
```

And data to

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "title": "Something",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "title": "Something Else",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yeah adding numbers is bad, it was just an example how it works, and what is happening.

Comment: if you change your answer to what the data should look like as an array I will select this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using incorrect JSON format. You duplicate the keys and the names should be unique. This should work

```
{  
       "categories":[  
          {  
             "title":"Something",
             "id":1
          },
          {  
             "title":"Something Else",
             "id":2
          }
       ]
    }
```

Other thing is that you are trying to append div elements on a table, the table must contains rows and columns. So if I understand your question this is the way your how to append your JSON elements to the table:
HTML:

```
<table id='table'>

</table>
```

script variables:

```
 var categoriesJson = [  
          {  
             "title":"Something",
             "id":0
          },
          {  
             "title":"Something Else",
             "id":1
          }
       ]
 var result = '';
```

script code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

            $.each(categoriesJson, function (i, item) {
                    result += "<tr><td><button id='"+item.id+"'>" + item.title + "</button></tr></td>"

                $('#table').append(result);
            });


       });
```

Comment: ツ that's giving me data back into the console. Now I need to get createButton to work but I'm sure I will figure it out. I see how this works now. Thank you. You're awesome!

Comment: I will update this code, this was the very first mistake I saw :)

Comment: appreciate the effort. I did it differently. My $(data.category).each(function (i)   was really it. Than I was able to do console.log(data.category[i].title); for example. I couldn't have done this without you though! You should checkout https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should change the line to something like this:

```
$(data.categories).each(function (key, value) {
    console.log("title", value.title);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you put the document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = createButton; in the each loop, in this way you write n times in the table and every time you put only the last "createButton"
I suggest you to init your variable before your each() loop, then concat every response from each iteration and only at the end push your data into the innerHTML.