# jQuery each only affects last item

Tags: javascript, jquery

My each statement will only affect the last element.

Why??

```js
$("span").each(function(index) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $(".divers-details").html($this.text() + "<br>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wine-name"><span>Cabernetj </span></div>
<div class="wine-name"><span>Caberneth </span></div>
<div class="wine-name"><span>Cabernetg </span></div>
<div class="wine-name"><span>Cabernetl</span></div>
<br/>
<p class="divers-details"></p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UJgAa/931/

Comment: It's being overwrited with every `each` iteration...

Comment: What is the expected behavior here?  The `divers-details` content keeps getting overwritten.

Comment: because... it is affecting them all, ***one after the other.***

Comment: How to display the entire iteration without overwriting?

Comment: You would use append.

Comment: Ho thx, so beginner..

Comment: Dupeish? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772916/jquery-each-method-returning-last-value

Comment: Short: `$(".divers-details").text( $('span').text() );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is your problem...

```
  $(".divers-details").html( $this.text() + "<br>");
```

The `html` method doesn't append to the .divers-details div, it simply replaces whatever is in it with the new value - meaning it replaces the contents.

What you want to do is use the `append` method, which (as the name implies) appends a value.  So in other words...

```
  $(".divers-details").append( $this.text() + "<br>");
```

You can read more about the append method at http://api.jquery.com/append/